# show and hide a box with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a news box with absolute positioning. when a user mouse over it i have create a script to animate it bottom value. so this is it.

```
(function(){
    var newsbox = $('div#news_div');

    newsbox.on('mouseover',function(){
        $(this).animate({'bottom':160},{duration:500});
        });
    newsbox.on('mouseleave',function(){
        $(this).delay(20000).animate({'bottom':55},{duration:500});
        });
    })();
```

so when i mouse over it again and again speedly its show unusual behaviours. could you plese advise me.

Comment: `mouseenter` may work instead of `mouseover`. Just check once I am not sure though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) method to stop any currently playing animations before starting the next animation.

```
(function(){
    var newsbox = $('div#news_div');

    newsbox.on('mouseover',function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({'bottom':160},{duration:500});
    });
    newsbox.on('mouseleave',function(){
    $(this).stop().delay(20000).animate({'bottom':55},{duration:500});
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a stop before you animation this will stop you firing an animation event if you hover quickly over links

```
(function(){
    var newsbox = $('div#news_div');

    newsbox.on('mouseover',function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({'bottom':160},{duration:500});
        });
    newsbox.on('mouseleave',function(){
        $(this).delay(20000).stop().animate({'bottom':55},{duration:500});
        });
    })();
```